# make wildcard targets

Tags: windows, compilation, makefile

Not much to say.

```
%.o: %.c
    @echo $<
```

```
C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>make foo.o
make: *** No rule to create »foo.o«. End.
```

I expect it to print `foo.c`. Why doesn't it work?

*Note: The last line of the last block is translated from german to english, the spelling might not be exactly as the english version prints out.*

---

**Platform**: Windows 7
**Architecture**: x86
**Make Version**: gnuwin32 3.81 (*25. Nov 2006*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `foo.c` exist?  If not, then Make won't consider this rule.

Comment: `O.o` That's it?! Man, and I was going to do [that one](http://bit.ly/LFiv5J)... This explains why my makefile scripts do not work ~.~ Thanks!

Comment: See _Static Pattern Rules_ in the make manual. Much less broken than simple pattern rules IMHO. (I your case you would write `f.o file2.o graphics.o: %.o: %.c` or somesuch.)